# Using doctrine, apiplatform and openapi generator leads to duplcate id field in the frontend side, how to solve this?

Tags: doctrine, api-platform.com, openapi-generator

I m using Symfony 4 with Doctrine and API Platform to build the backend of my application.
I generated entities using `php bin/console make:entity`. Each class has an id field like this one

```
/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CategoryRepository::class)
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    ...
```

I generated the api doc file `php bin/console api:openapi:export --output=swagger.json`
Then I use OpenAPI Generator to generate the client part for the frontend `npx openapi-generator-cli generate -i swagger.json -g typescript-angular --enable-post-process-file -o build`
The resulting model file `categoryJsonld.ts` containes 2 id fields

```
export interface CategoryJsonld { 
    readonly context?: string | any | null;
    readonly id?: string;
    readonly type?: string;
    readonly id?: number;
    ...
```

The field `id`is duplicated and the frontend doesn't compile.
I guess the first id stands for `@id` defined in jsons+ld format.
Any idea to solve/prevent the duplication of `id` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your Content-Type to application/json to exclude the extra json-ld fields. However this will result in problems when you have collections and need to use pagination, because you would need some meta data that is not being returned with plain json. I would recommend changing your own id field to something else like uuid as the id, type and context names are reserved for json-ld format.  Try just changing the getters and/or setters name first OpenApi should generate it correctly then. e.x. In your entity change getId() to getUuid() or you could just add an annotation to change the serialized name for example: @SerializedName("uuid") above the getId()